# Change Stripe example email in webhooks triggers

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to be able to pass an email into the webhook I trigger. I have a setup where after a user pays I want to update their record on Mailchimp. To properly test this without pushing to production (or running a local server open to the internet) I need to pass an email to `stripe trigger checkout.session.completed` so that it can find an email in Mailchimp. Right now the email is always `stripe@example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to pass in custom data to stripe-cli triggers currently. Instead you probably want to use a service like ngrok.io to test this in a local environment.

Comment: Yeah ngrok is what I'm using now. It's not terrible but with only a single test/sandbox environment it makes it hard to test with more than one person. Thank you!